# Failure in pip installing biopython

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

When I write pip install biopython on Bash, I get the error messages "error: subprocess-exited-with-error" and further down "error: legacy-install-failure" in the output. I can confirm using python --version and pip --version that both exist (version 2.7 and 22.1.4), and I can pip install other packages like matplotlib, so I know the problem is not with pip install itself. The output also tells me there is something likely wrong with the biopython package itself. How can this be fixed so I can pip install biopython?

Comment: https://codecary.com/solved-error-legacy-install-failure/

Comment: I don't think biopython still supports python 2. You should try to switch to python 3

Comment: @bli is correct. you should use python 3. Biopython 1.76 was the last release to support python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Use [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html) instead, for example:

```
conda create --name biopython biopython
```